# Invalidated digital signature in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

It happened to me that MS Access rejected my certificate and denied to sign the file during save with a message:

> "Modifications to the database or project have invalidated the
>   associated digital signature"

How to force MS Access to sign the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to:

1. decompile the file from command prompt (making a copy before decompiling should be welcome)

   "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\MSACCESS.EXE" "d:\My Documents\access\mayapp.mdb" /decompile
2. compile the code again in VBA editor
3. compact/repair the file

Comment: Don't link to Experts Exchange, man; they obfuscate their answers, and the link doesn't add anything to your answer.

Comment: They obfuscate at the top of their page but still the answer is available a bit lower. Isn't it good to post a source? I found it there so I would like to keep a link to it. I do not see any guidelines for making answers within faq... Oh now I see - when going directly to their page the answer is totally hidden (it is shown only for google queries) - I will remove the link then.